# Edit Razer Synapse Macro in text editor

Tags: windows, macos, macros, razer-mouse, razer-synapse

I do have a Razer Naga Mouse and A4Tech X7 keyboard. For keyboard i can easily open macro file (XML file) and edit (copy + paste parts of it, reuse existing ones etc). I could create an easy wrappers for commands like mouseClick, mouserRightClick, dragAndDrop in language of choice which is JavaScript -- since its just modifying pre-existing template.

And basically that allows me to create more powerful scripts for my device.

With Razer though you get overpriced mouse that comes with Synapse, that is not even allowed you to easily manipulate with your own macros. The only positive thing there is UI + cloud. But inability to edit makes it super poor choice :(

Is there any way to edit the macro files in Text Editor (VSCode or so)?

Comment: If you find its overpriced don't buy their products? Depending on how they set it up you won't be able to edit them. Did you try to find the files the macro(s) are stored in?

Comment: i tried and failed in OSX. In windows seems i've seen the folder somewhere, but not sure if its possible to edit it there :) will anyway update the question when find smth :) wonder that no one tried to do the same... macro ui's are awful, not only in Synapse. Script abilities that provided by autohotkey or such apps - way better.... maybe perception is that you will create a macro that binds 2-3 buttons together...

Comment: Looks like they're stored in the ProgramData folder in Windows according to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/389pfe/razer_synapse_macro_folder/).

Comment: Just searched for text editing of macro files and after I looked through my files I found the `.xml` files at `C:\ProgramData\Razer\Synapse\Accounts\YourAccountID\Macros`, hope that helps if you still have the issue... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are saved as `.xml` files at:

`C:\ProgramData\Razer\Synapse\Accounts\`***`YourAccountID`***`\Macros`

To apply changes made to these `.xml` files you need to restart Razer Synapse.

---

This at least applies to the macros of my Razer DeathStalker Chroma keyboard in Razer Synapse 2.21, but I'd assume this includes every macro for every device.

Comment: im waiting for razer synaps v3. its awesome and supports what i need (xml macros, easy file import/export etc)... as of synapse v2 i would say its possible to do it via hacks, but definitely not designed for that :(

Comment: @ValeriiVasin Looks promising, but there are only a handful supported devices as of now.

Comment: i talked to support, they promised support old devices in Q3

Comment: @ValeriiVasin Let's hope so! ;)